# Simple CGO example fails compilation with "duplicate symbol" error

Tags: go, cgo

I want to make a simple example of calling C code from Go with CGO. But for some reason I can't achieve desired. Compilation fails with the following error:

```
 go build main.go 
# awesomeProject1/print
duplicate symbol '_do_print' in:
    $WORK/b002/_x002.o
    $WORK/b002/_x003.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The code:

```c
// print/print.c
#include <stdio.h>

void do_print(char * x){
printf("%s", x);
}
```

```golang
// print/print.go
package print

// #include <print.c>
import "C"

func DoPrint() {
    C.do_print(C.CString("Hello!"))
}
```

```golang
// main.go
package main

import "awesomeProject1/print"

func main() {
    print.DoPrint()
}
```

If I make `do_print` function static it compiles but I wouldn't be able to do that for 3rd party code I want to integrate with later.
Am I missing some essential piece from documentation? Tutorials are all alike and claim to work where my example fails. Please help!
Go version 1.16.4

Comment: The C file and the Go files both get compiled, so the contents of `print.c` gets compiled twice. Generally, including a `.c` file is a bad idea.

Comment: I  got it! It works now. Would you like to create an answer or should I?

Comment: I wrote up an answer. I went into more detail, since my comment wasn't much of an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things going on here:

1. `go build` compiles `*.c` in addition to `*.go`<sup>1</sup>
2. `#include <print.c>` is exactly equivalent to overwriting the include statement with the contents of `print.c`

As a result, you are compiling the contents of `print.c` twice: once when `print.c` is compiled by CC, and once when `print.go` is compiled by CGo. Thus, the object files for `print.c` and `print.go` each contain all of the exported symbols defined in `print.c`. So you get two copies of `do_print`. Making `do_print` static works because a function declared as `static` will not be exported by CC.

**Including a `.c` file (e.g. `#include <file.c>`) is pretty much always a bad idea.** If you have a legitimate reason to `#include` function bodies, the convention is to use a header (`.h`) file. This is what C++ templating libraries do (like Boost, IIRC). Because C files normally are *not* included, and H files normally *are* included, including a C file subverts expectations and thus is likely to cause confusion and problems.

---

<sup>1</sup> IIRC, Go will compile C files in a package if any of the Go files in the package import `"C"`. That is, if no Go files in a package use CGo, Go will ignore C files in that package.